# Merge multiple columns data into one pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to read a csv file and then trying to merge 23 columns into a new one with pandas.
I've tried the following with or without lambda and without df.assign:

> df = df.assign(X = lambda x: df.A.astype(str) + df.B.astype(str) + df.C.astype(str) + df.D.astype(str) + df.E.astype(str) + df.F.astype(str)
>                    + df.G.astype(str) + df.H.astype(str) + df.I.astype(str) + df.J.astype(str) + df.K.astype(str) + df.L.astype(str)
>                    + df.M.astype(str) + df.N.astype(str) + df.O.astype(str) + df.P.astype(str) + df.Q.astype(str) + df.R.astype(str)
>                    + df.S.astype(str) + df.T.astype(str) + df.U.astype(str) + df.V.astype(str) + df.W.astype(str))

However I'm coming across a limitation of Pandas where i can only merge 19 columns into one. So the above code only works if i take the last 4 columns of it.
Is there any work around it? Or is it Pandas limitation?
The following line is an example of my data with column X as my aim:

> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X
>   GRB,D,43746,CL,S,19400,0A,00506100,,3380810506105,MEN ANTIPERSP DEODTNT STICK,WES,550,1,,,MAS,20180403,100309,MAS,0,0,20180403,GRBD43746CLS194000A005061003380810506105MEN ANTIPERSP DEODTNT STICKWES5501MAS20180403100309MAS0020180403

This is the error that i'm getting when i try to merge all 23 columns:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1249, placement implies 1

1249 are the lines of my CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid all of that by simply aggregating along the axis.

```
df = df.agg(lambda x: '/'.join(x), axis = 1)
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abcdef'), 'b': list('ghijkl')})
df = df.astype('str') #To Aggregate Strings

df['New Column'] = df.agg(lambda x: '/'.join(x), axis = 1)

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
   a  b New Column
0  a  g        a/g
1  b  h        b/h
2  c  i        c/i
3  d  j        d/j
4  e  k        e/k
5  f  l        f/l
```

Comment: How do i assign the aggregation to a new column?
With your example i get error
TypeError: ('sequence item 2: expected string, long found', u'occurred at index 0')
As i have different data types in each column!